# What is the difference between CustomPainter and CustomClipper?

Tags: flutter

I am currently reading about Flutter and came to know that shapes can be created using CustomPainter and CustomClipper. Shapes like Rectangle, oval etc.. can be created using both so what is the difference between them and when should either of them be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### CustomClipper

A clipper is used to restrict the rendering to a particular area. The rendering engine will only "paint" the pixels inside of the defined area. A `CustomClipper` will be mostly used with a `ClipPath` widget.

```dart
class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    // Implement your custom clipper path
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

ClipPath(
  clipper: MyCustomClipper(),
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
);
```

- [CustomClipper Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html)
- [ClipPath Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html)

### CustomPainter

This interface is used alongside the `CustomPaint` which provides a canvas on which you can draw images and shapes.

```dart
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Implement your custom painter
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

CustomPaint(
  painter: MyCustomPainter(),
);
```

- [CustomPainter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html)
- [CustomPaint Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html)

To resume: `CustomClipper` is restricting the painting area, while `CustomPainter` gives you a canvas to paint freely.

### Which one to use ?

While you might be able to acomplish similar results with both depending on your use case it might be easier to use `CustomClipper` or `CustomPainter`.

For example if you only want to have some custom shape for a `Container` or an `Image` it will be much easier to do it with a `CustomClipper` compared to a `CustomPainter` as you will only need to define the path in which your widget will be rendered and you will still have access to all the properties of your widget.

Now let's take another example, if you want to create your own `CircularProgressIndicator` widget. In this case you might have a hard time by using the `CustomClipper` while thanks to `CustomPainter` you will be able to draw your widget  much more freely and it will also be easier to animate. (If you take a look at how the `ProgressIndicator` are coded you will see that they are using `CustomPainter`)